# printf not giving me the correct output, maybe scanf is to blame

Tags: c, function, printf, scanf

Writing code to accept user input such as P0 x1 y1 to store in a nested structure as a point, and the same with two other points. However when inputting with `scanf()` and checking `printf()`, I am not getting the right numbers, like `scanf()` is reading something else, advice would be great, thanks!

```
float x, x2, y, y2;
char Q, input;

nested triangle;

scanf("%c", &input);

if (input == 'Q' || input =='q')
  return;

else
  {
  scanf(" %c %f%f",&input, &triangle.P0.x, &triangle.P0.y);
  printf("points are\n%f \n%f \n", triangle.P0.x, triangle.P0.y);
}

scanf("%c", &input);

if (input == 'Q' || input =='q')
  return;

else
  {
  scanf(" %c %f%f",&input, &triangle.P1.x, &triangle.P1.y);
  printf("points are\n %f \n%f \n",input, triangle.P1.x, triangle.P1.y);
}
```

Comment: For starters, always check the return value of `scanf`. The code is incomplete. Please give a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `scanf("%c", &input);`, then this will read in a new line from a previous input into `input`. This is usually not what you intend.

Therefore, write `scanf(" %c", &input);` (note the blank before the `%c`) to skip white spaces.

Note further that `%c` will just read in one character; if you intend to read in `P0`, you need a string, e.g. `char[3]` and format specifier `%s`.

Comment: Ok i"ll give that a try